# Is there anyway to use Behat within a phpunit test case?

Tags: php, phpunit, behat, fuelphp, mink

I've been using the Behat english-like test language (Gherkin?) to write test scripts but have quickly come up it's significant limitations.

If I could execute these tests in PHP within the phpunit test scripts that I have set up I could significant expand the tests that I could add. (I'm using FuelPHP).

I've been tinkering around for a few hours trying to get Behat to execute inside a PHPUNIT test script but have not had much luck.

Is this possible?

Comment: What limitations are you talking about? Behat is for integrational testing, phpunit is for unit testing - two different concepts.

Comment: e.g. comparing that a piece of data is the same on page A and is is on page B. Comparing data from two different pages. (I know that I could basically cheat and write it into some heavy-duty .feature files but I was thinking it would be more natural just to run through in PHP and make the necessary assertions as I went along.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you are confusing something, because what you are saying doesn't make a lot of sense. If you having a hard time expressing the logic with the code, you should ask a specific question on that.

Behat and Mink are both written in PHP, you write your contexts in PHP, there is a gadzillion of plugins to make the life easier (also written in php). As the matter of fact, all your tests are executed in PHP when you run them… Yup!

If you want to compare data from two pages you can simply create a step like this:

```
/**
 * @Then /^the page "(.+)" and the page "(.+)" content should somehow compare$/
 */
public function assertPageContentCompares($page1, $page2)
{
    $session = $this->getSession();
    $session->visit($page1);
    $page1contents = $session->getPage()->getHtml();

    $session->visit($page2);
    $page2contents = $session->getPage()->getHtml();

    // Compare stuff…
}
```

Besides the obvious, you can use PHPUnit in with Behat / Mink to make the assertions, i.e., in your step definitions. Most (in not all) PHPUnit assertions are static methods, using them is as simple as this:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase::assertSame("", "");
```

You can use Selenium (probably other frameworks too) with PHPUnit, if this is more about unit testing than functional testing, [the official documentation tells how](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html).

If you simply hate Gherkin then there's not much you can do with Behat – it's at the core of it. With PhpStorm 8 out there is a pretty good support for it, you can easily navigate around your code and refactor it quickly. If that doesn't cut it, there's another great alternative to Behat called [Codeception](http://codeception.com/), where you use pure PHP to define your tests. Maybe that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand that writing these wouldn't be a "unit test" per sey but it's a useful place to put tests.

What you wrote above is pretty much exactly what I wanted to do but writing it as a feature seems really cumbersome and was hoping to be able to just write it directly in PHP (which I would suspect would be faster and easier for progammers to work with).

you might be right, I'm not sure i have the terminology down: Gherkin, Mink, Behat...

Comment: It does take time to get the head around with Behat and the rest of the family. And I agree that Gherkin is not a very "conservative" way of coding, I'm not a fan of it either. I was also wondering for awhile if the actual execution would be faster in Codeception, because it doesn't need to do all the parsing. There are many pros and cons, if you are deciding which way to go – try them both if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use the library I created: [jonathanjfshaw/phpunitbehat](https://github.com/jonathanjfshaw/phpunitbehat).

Your phpunit tests will looks like this:

```
    namespace MyProject\Tests;

    use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
    use PHPUnitBehat\TestTraits\BehatTestTrait;

    class MyTestBase extends TestCase {
      use BehatTestTrait;
    }
```

```
    namespace MyProject\Tests;

    class MyTest extends MyTestBase {

      protected $feature = <<<'FEATURE'
    Feature: Demo feature
      In order to demonstrate testing a feature in phpUnit
      We define a simple feature in the class
    Scenario: Success
        Given a step that succeeds
    Scenario: Failure
        When a step fails

      Scenario: Undefined
        Then there is a step that is undefined
    FEATURE;

      /**
       * @Given a step that succeeds
       */
      public function aStepThatSucceeds() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
      }

      /**
       * @When a step fails
       */
      public function aStepFails() {
        $this->assertTrue(false);
      }
    }
```

I wrote [a blog post explaining why I think this is not a bad idea](https://medium.com/@jonathanjfshaw/write-better-tests-by-using-behat-with-phpunit-ddb08d449b73).